# How to give a range for BigQuery pivot rows to column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

I found a very useful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71891610/bigquery-sql-convert-array-to-columns#:%7E:text=Typically%20in%20BigQuery%20this%20is%20accomplished%20using%20CROSS,UNNEST%20%28raw.a%29%20AS%20vals%29%20SELECT%20%2A%20FROM%20long_format) to what I want to do. Assuming I am doing exactly the same thing but I have 100 values for offset and don't want to do `IN (1,...99)` and can't use `BigQuery Procedural Language`, is there any way to give a range to the offset values:

```
    SELECT *
  FROM long_format PIVOT(
    ANY_VALUE(vals) AS vals 
    FOR offset IN (RANGE or anything better than enumerating 0 to 99)
)
```

Comment: clarify - you don't want  to (or cannot) use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, which is the most appropriate direction here?

Comment: I cannot as part of the ETL rules for this particular job.

Comment: I would say - NO - " there NO way to give a range to the offset values:" within the PIVOT w/o using dynamic PIVOT via EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. So you might need to revisit your requirements

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding and @Mikhail Berlyant comment:

> There is no way to give a **range** to the **offset** **values** within the
> PIVOT w/o using dynamic PIVOT via EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Posting the answer as ***community wiki*** for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.